# AngularJS - Implement $locationChangeStart to go to the first page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When in back button, I need to go to the first page. I'm not using session.

I try to use this, but I not seems work, possible its because I put it in a wrong place.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
  function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
  event.preventDefault();
  window.history.forward();
 });
```

I put this code in the top of my app

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "first page"?

Comment: I mean the initial page of the app flow. Also could be  another specifc page in the app.